# How do I use a JNDI entry in my application running on WildFly

Tags: jndi, wildfly

I am trying to read a JNDI value in my web application using the WildFly naming subsystem, similar to [WildFly JNDI Reference](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/JNDI+Reference)

Here is the relevent section of my standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0" >
  <bindings>
    <simple name="java:global/myId" value="ID001" type="java.lang.String" />
  </bindings>
  <remote-naming/>
</subsystem>
```

Here is the code I'm using to lookup the JNDI

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:global/myId")
private String myId;
```

When I deploy, the field myId doesn't get set and I get the following output on the console:

```
17:18:43,115 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-1) Creating Service {http://example.com}MyAppService from class com.abc.MyAppPort
17:18:43,428 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-1) Setting the server's publish address to be http://localhost:9080/MA/MyAppService
17:18:43,443 FINE  [org.apache.cxf.resource.DefaultResourceManager] (MSC service thread 1-1) resolving resource <com.example.impl.MyApp/myId> type <class java.lang.String>
17:18:43,443 FINE  [org.apache.cxf.resource.DefaultResourceManager] (MSC service thread 1-1) resolving resource <null> type <class java.lang.String>
17:18:43,443 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector] (MSC service thread 1-1) failed to resolve resource com.example.impl.MyApp/myId
```

**Update:** If I do the lookup in jboss-web.xml as follows:

```
<resource-env-ref>
  <resource-env-ref-name>myId</resource-env-ref-name>
  <resource-env-ref-type>java.lang.String</resource-env-ref-name>
  <lookup-name>java:global/myId</lookup-name>
</resource-env-ref>
```

and remove the lookup from the annotation:

```
@Resource
private String myId;
```

myId is set as expected (the cxf tracing above still occurs).

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Nothing appears to be incorrect about that injection. The Resource annotation is from `javax.annotation.Resource` correct?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've done the necessary to [integrate cxf with wildfly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Apache+CXF+integration). From your log trace it seems that **cxf is taking over wildfly** to proceed to @Resource injection. The configuration and code you've done is correct.

Comment: I haven't done anything explicit with but the project is a jaxws generated from a wsdl, so I guess thats why cxf is involved.

Comment: Cxf is a specific implémentation. Have a look at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JAX-WS+Tools?_sscc=t